# Validation with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, forms

There are similar questions, but I can't find the way I want to check the form submit data.

I like to check the form submit data for phone number and email. I check as follows, but it doesn't work.

How can I make it correct?

```
<script>
    function validateForm() {

        var x = document.forms["registerForm"]["Email"].value;
        if (x == null || x == "") {
            alert("Email number must be filled out.");
            return false;
        }
        else if(!/@./.test(x)) {
            alert("Email number must be in correct format.");
            return false;
        }

        x = document.forms["registerForm"]["Phone"].value;
        if (x == null || x == "" ) {
            alert("Phone number must be filled out.");
            return false;
        }
        else if(!/[0-9]+()-/.test(x)) {
          alert("Phone number must be in correct format.");
          return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

For email I'd like to check only "@" and "." are included in the email address.

For phone number, I'd like to check ()-+[0-9] and one space are only accepted for phone number, for example +95 9023222, +95-1-09098098, (95) 902321. How can I check it?

There will be another check at the server, so there isn't any need to check in detail at form submit.

Comment: Use html 5 validation 
using pattern attribute
like <input id="phone" placeholder="888-888-8888" required pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

#### HTML part

```
<div class="form_box">
    <div class="input_box">
        <input maxlength="64" type="text" placeholder="Email*" name="email" id="email" />
        <div id="email-error" class="error-box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

<div class="form_box">
    <div class="input_box ">
        <input maxlength="10" type="text" placeholder="Phone*" name="phone" id="phone" />
        <div id="phone-error" class="error-box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

#### Your script

```
var email = $('#email').val();
var phone = $('#phone').val();
var email_re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,3}))$/;
var mobile_re = /^[0-9]{10}$/g;

if ($.trim(email) == '') {
    $('#email').val('');
    $('#email-error').css('display', 'block');
    $('#email-error').html('Please enter your Email');
} else if (!email.match(email_re)) {
    $('#email-error').css('display', 'block');
    $('#email-error').html('Please enter valid Email');
}

if ($.trim(phone) == '') {
    $('#phone').val('');
    $('#phone-error').css('display', 'block');
    $('#phone-error').html('Please enter your Phone Number');
} else if (!phone.match(mobile_re)) {
    $('#phone-error').css('display', 'block');
    $('#phone-error').html('Please enter valid Phone Number');
} else {
    $('#phone-error').css('display', 'none');
    $('#phone-error').html('');
}
```

Comment: Glad i could help you:)

Answer (score 3):

#### Email validation

From http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/email-validation.php

```
function ValidateEmail(mail)
{
    if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(myForm.emailAddr.value))
    {
        return (true)
    }

    alert("You have entered an invalid email address!")
    return (false)
}
```

#### Phone number validation

From http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/phone-no-validation.php.

```
function phonenumber(inputtxt)
{
    var phoneno = /^\d{10}$/;
    if ((inputtxt.value.match(phoneno))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("message");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could of course write the validation part yourself, but you could also use one of the many validation libraries.

One widely used one is [Parsley](http://parsleyjs.org). It's very easy to use. Just include the `.js` and `.css` and add some information to the form and its elements like this ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vhv5d2sm/1/)):

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="parsley.min.js"></script> 
<form data-parsley-validate>
    <input data-parsley-type="email" name="email"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 has an email validation facility. You can check if you are using HTML5:

```
<form>
    <input type="email" placeholder="me@example.com">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Also, for another option, you can check [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/Ra85j/).